# Path format is illegal

Tags: c#, logfile

I want to ask about a  easy question , but I faced a problem.
I want to get the time when the program is executed

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

And I want to output a .log file , the file name will have program execution time

```
String path2 = "C:\\temp"+DateTime.Now+".log";
StreamWriter path = File.CreateText(path2);
path.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

But it is telling me Path format is illegal.

And I want ask another question

```
string a12 = aaa.Element("a12").tostring();
String path2 = "C:\\temp" + a12.ToString + ".log";
```

But it tell me "Path format is illegal"

How can I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because DateTime.Now converted to string by default contains time information (e.g. 8:53). Semicolon is illegal in path name.

If you meant only date to be in your file name, you could use:

```
String path2 = "C:\\temp" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + ".log";
```

(Edit) For some cultures this still can lead to invalid values, so as others pointed out, it is best to use explicit formatter:

```
String path2 = "C:\\temp" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".log";
```

Comment: I want to ask another problem
string a12 = aaa.Element("a12").tostring();
String path2 = "C:\\temp" + a12.ToString + ".log";

But it tell me "Path format is illegal"
How can I fix it

Comment: That means Element("a12") after conversion to string contains characters that are illegal for file names.

`Path.GetInvalidPathChars` static method returns array of illegal characters.

Comment: String path2 = "C:\\temp" + a12.ToArray() + ".log"
Can I use "System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars" here?

Comment: `a12.ToArray()` - are you sure you want to use array as a part of file name? Have you checked content of `path2` variable after this call?

Answer (score 1):

You want to escape your \ in the "" quoted string, and also there are characters in the result of DateTime.Now that cannot be in paths.  You'll need to escape/replace those as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you put `DateTime.Now` into a path, you risk adding characters that aren't valid as a path (like the `:` separator. That is the reason you get this error message.

You could replace it with a `.`:

```
string path2 = Path.Combine
               ( @"C:\temp\"
               , DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd.HH24.mm.ss")
               , ".log"
               );
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now probably contains illegal characters depending on your local system settings. To get a valid and consistent file name independent on the culture the system is installed in you should create the log file name by hand, for instance like this:

```
String path2 = "C:\\temp" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".log";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String path2 = String.Format("C:\\temp{0}.log", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Since filename cannot take "/" which was created by DateTime.Now.ToString("d") and hence creating issue.